# Flutter Web - Pick Image using Phone

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, imagepicker

I have an application built using flutter web and I am trying to upload a picture from  the web page through a phone. I am using image_picker package but when I call picker.getImage(...) it is not opening the phone gallery. Can you please provide support of what additionally I need to add to my app.

Dependencies:
image_picker: ^0.6.7+11
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

Code:
`final picker = ImagePicker(); final pickedImage = await picker.getImage( source: ImageSource.gallery, //Properties to decrease quality and storage space and accelerate the apps performacne imageQuality: 20, //Value between 0 and 100 //maxWidth: 150, )` 
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Use this image_picker_for_web
Release 2.0.0

```
dependencies:
  image_picker_for_web: ^2.0.0

import 'package:image_picker_for_web/image_picker_for_web.dart';
```

pickImage()
The arguments maxWidth, maxHeight and imageQuality are not supported on the web.

But i doesn't know how... if you know please share example please.